# Renaming Exported files from Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, bigdata

We are currently using Spark Job on Databricks which do processing on our data lake which in S3. 
Once the processing is done we export our result to S3 bucket using normal 
df.write()

The issue is when we write dataframe to S3 the name of file is controlled by Spark, but as per our agreement we need to rename this files to a meaningful name.

Since S3 doesn't have renaming feature we are right now using boto3 to copy and paste file with expected name.
This process is very complex and not scalable with more client getting onboard.

Do we have any better solution to rename exported files from spark to S3 ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it directly in Spark's save

Spark uses Hadoop File Format, which requires data to be partitioned - that's why you have part- files.  If the file is small enough to fit into memory, one work around is to convert to a pandas dataframe and save as csv from there.

```
df_pd = df.toPandas()
df_pd.to_csv("path")
```